# jquery context-menu disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I'm using the jquery context-menu plugin. However, when choosing an input that is disabled, the context-menu toggle won't work. Here is the jsfiddle. 
The jsfiddle is quite self explanatory, the `disabled` tag added to the input makes the plugin not behave as expected.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb6urLcf/3/)
And the actual code

```
<h1>INPUT DISABLED NOT WORKING</h1>
<input class='notworking' disabled>
<h1>REGULAR DIV WORKING</h1>
<div class="working" style='with:50px;height:50px;background:red;'>
</div>

$.contextMenu({
selector: 'div.working',
trigger: 'left',
callback: function(key, options) {},
items: {
"P9": {
  name: "Set AAA grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P8": {
  name: "Set AA grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P7": {
  name: "Set A grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P6": {
  name: "Set BBB grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P5": {
  name: "Set BB grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P4": {
  name: "Set B grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P3": {
  name: "Set CCC grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P2": {
  name: "Set CC grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P1": {
  name: "Set C grade",
  icon: "edit"
   }
 }
  });
 $.contextMenu({
 selector: 'input.notworking',
trigger: 'left',
callback: function(key, options) {},
items: {
"P9": {
  name: "Set AAA grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P8": {
  name: "Set AA grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P7": {
  name: "Set A grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P6": {
  name: "Set BBB grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P5": {
  name: "Set BB grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P4": {
  name: "Set B grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P3": {
  name: "Set CCC grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P2": {
  name: "Set CC grade",
  icon: "edit"
},
"P1": {
  name: "Set C grade",
  icon: "edit"
}
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers prevent disabled elements to be focussed, this overrides javascript. If you change `disabled` to `readonly` the context script works and the input is still protected from user changes. You can make it look disabled by adding some css colors (preferrably in your stylesheet):

```
<input class="notworking" readlony style="background:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #ccc;">
```